# Permalink for pages

Tags: permalinks, pages

As you know we can change the post permalink as we want

```
/%postname%.htm -->/mypostname.htm
```

Can we do the same for the pages also?

```
/%pagename%.htm -->/mypagename.htm
```

permalink for the pages is %pagename% whe we use the custom permalink for the post.

Comment: Please add more explanation to the question. Put in the reason behind the question and let us know what have you tried :)

Comment: I am trying to permalinks for my page with htm or html.

Comment: Have you tried setting it to see what happens?

Comment: On the settings I can decide only for post. and becomes directly for the page /pagename notlike pagename.htm as i have done for postname.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permalinks work for everything, pages, posts, etc...

Have a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: I have checked already but icould find an exact answer

Comment: What do you mean, just adjust your permalink structure to /%postname%/ and it will all work as u want ;)

Comment: What i like having like mypage.htm or htm

Comment: Never recommended to use a filetype with WP. Just end with %postname%

Comment: I have mademany searches and icouldnt find a answer formy question.